# Apache service not started (-1)

Tags: apache, xampp

While trying to start Apache service through xampp on my windows 7, I get this:

```
Apache service not started (-1)
Busy...
```

What could be the reasons for this failure? How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Have you considered using a ready-made installer package like XAMPP for your first steps? It makes installation much easier. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: why people are putting -1 for my questions , my reputation is going down and down and its just 1 now ... :-(

Comment: You should read the FAQ and ask on topic questions. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @tsndiff they are very, very basic questions that can be helped by some research. There are many helpful resources on how to troubleshoot an Apache installation out there on the web, available to everyone who bothers to read them. Google `Apache service not started (-1)` for example - you'll find dozens of forum threads concerned with this very problem. SO is not meant to be a Q&A site, not a troubleshooting support resource.

Comment: See for example  http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=21180

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you have installed apache as a service:

1. Right Click `My Computer` and select `manage`
2. Choose `Services And Applications/Services`
3. Find `Apache` in the list
4. Right click and select `start`

Answer (score 1):

Something is blocking your Apache Default port (most probably 80).
Check for :

1. Antivirus.
2. Firewall.
3. Another server (IIS).
4. Skype.

Those are the most frequent reasons for Apache not to take off.

More info will be helpful to furhter troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: until yesterday it was working fine  and I know skype is a problem for it , so I even shut it down , but still no use

Comment: You may download some tool to see what open ports do you have, if you Apache port is there - someone is using it that's why Apache won't start.

Comment: Or perhaps just open your commandline and execute `netstat -an` to see all listening ports. You could also try to telnet or similar to port 80 to see if it's open or not. `telnet 127.0.0.1 80`